# Cannot seem to resolve ambiguity in Antlr Grammar

Tags: parsing, antlr4, arithmetic-expressions

I am creating the simplest grammar possible that basically recognizes arithmetic expressions. The grammar needs to correctly follow arithmetic operators precedence rules (PEMDAS), and for that I placed `expr ('*'|'/') term`  before `expr ('+'|'-') term` to ensure this precedence.
This is the arithmetic.g4 file that I have:

```
/*Productions */
 
expr: expr ('*'|'/') term
    | expr ('+'|'-') term
    | term
    ;
term: '('expr')'
    | ID
    | NUM
    ;

/*Tokens */
ID: [a-z]+;
NUM: [0-9]+;

WS:  [\t\r\n]+->skip;
```

The output of the grammar is however not what it should be. For example for the arithmetic expression **4 * (3 + 10)** I get the below parse tree (which is absolutely not correct):

[image]

Any suggestions on how I can change the grammar to get what I am looking for. I am new to antlr and am not sure what mistake I am making. (jbtw my OS is windows)

Comment: What's incorrect about that parse tree? Precedence doesn't even come into play for that expression given the parentheses? There's really no other way to parse that expression. Did you maybe mean to use the input `4 * 3 + 10`? But for that one, you should actually be getting the correct parse tree. An example where your grammar would produce the wrong parse tree would be `4 + 3 * 10`.

Comment: Please clarify what you were expecting. I am not an ANTLR user but it seems to me that the tree matches the input semantically. You do have explicit parenthesis here, so operator precedence doesn't really seem to apply for this example. Are you concerned with the redundant `expr` nodes, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm assuming that you've made a mistake in your example (which looks fine) and you really meant that you're getting the wrong tree for the input `4 + 3 * 10`, so that's what I'm going to answer. If that's not what you meant, please clarify.)

You're right that ANTLR resolves ambiguities based on the order of rules, but that does not apply to your grammar because your grammar is not ambiguous. For an input like `4 + 3 * 10`, there's only one way to parse it according to your grammar: with `*` being the outer operator, with `4 + 3` as its left and `10` as its right operand. The correct way (`+` as the outer operator with `3 * 10` as the right operand) doesn't work with your grammar because `3 * 10` is not a valid `term` and the right operand needs to be a `term` according to your grammar.

In order to get an ambiguity that's resolved in the way you want, you'll need to make both operands of your operators `expr`s.

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right I understand how I was wrong there. Thanks a lot for your help and sorry for the extremely trivial question.